# Comparing months and days without years

Tags: logic

So, I essentially have 4 fields: M1 D1, M2 D2

They represent month 1 day 1, month 2 day 2

Examples:

- 10, 1, 5, 31           October 1st to May 31st (spans two different years)
- 6, 1, 7, 4                 June 1st to July 4th
- 7, 5, 8, 1                 July 5th to August 1st
- 8, 2, 9, 30     August 2nd to September 30th

Essentially I have a month and day and want to know which one of those records it is in between. I don't need anything language specific, however I do have them in a table and am attempting to solve the problem with SQL. I would just like someone to help me with the logic.

Thanks so much!

Comment: if I understand correctly, you will have for example a value like {mnth,dy} and you want to see if that value(pair) is between the interval [{7,5},{8,1}], for example?

Comment: @MichaelM. that is correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the logic I came up with that worked for every day:

```
WHERE (m BETWEEN m1 AND m2 AND d BETWEEN d1 AND d2)
OR (m BETWEEN m1 AND m2 AND ( (m = m1 AND d >= d1) OR (m = m2 AND d <= d2) OR (m > m1 AND m < m2) ))
OR (m1 > m2 AND ( m >= m1 OR m <= m2) AND d BETWEEN d1 AND d2)
OR (m1 > m2 AND ( m >= m1 OR m <= m2) AND ( (m = m1 AND d >= d1) OR (m = m2 AND d <= d2) OR (m > m1 OR m < m2) ))
```

I also updated the examples to include a situation not realized in the originals:

- 10,6 to 5,5
- 5,6 to 7,4
- 7,5 to 8,1
- 8,2 to 10,5

Answer (score 0):

So you have a month and day in a variable, and want to match the record.  I think the easiest logic is to convert these values to "numbers" that are comparable.  Something like:

```
from t
where (month*100+day between m1*100+d1 and m2*100+d2 and m1*100+d1 <= m2*100+d2) or
      (month*100+day not between m2*100+d2+1 and m1*100+d1-1and m2*100+m2 < m1*100+d1)
```

The rule for "100" is just that it is bigger than then longest month (31) and it produces something that looks reasonable (1001 and 531) for the first case.

Comment: 12/30 should fit into the first example, however 1230 is not between (1001 and 531)

Comment: @JamesKleeh . . . You are right.  That second clause should be `not between`.  This might introduce an off-by-1 error . . . depending on whether 10/01 and 5/31 satisfy the conditions.  As written, they don't.  Judicious use of "+1" and "-1" would fix that problem.

Comment: I ran this against every day in the year and the only days it did not work were 10/1 and 5/31